# MySQL & concurrent updates showing for users in simultaneous connections w/o disconnect

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-concurrency

We have a MySQL database managed through phpmyadmin. One of my coworkers is insisting that the database will not parse updates to the DB until all simultaneous connections are closed. I think he is saying that if we have 20 users connected to the same DB making updates to it, all 20 users have to disconnect before the updates go through. ie, if an update is made to a table by one user, none of the other users will be able to see it until they all disconnect. Is this the case?

I've looked around and can't find an answer. [The MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html) doesn't really say as far as I can tell, and although there are some similar questions here on SO, none I've found answer this question. My coworker says this is a limitation present in nearly all DB's and DBMS. I don't think this is true, but I care much more about knowing the truth than being right, and I'll happily change my stance if I find out this is true.

The version of phpmyadmin we're running is 2.11.11.3, and the version of MySQL is 5.0.77.

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is no such restriction.